# Excel, VBA: Copy image control's picture to an image control on a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following to populate an image control on the first sheet of the workbook:

```
 Private Sub Image1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     On Error GoTo ErrHandler
     Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Application.GetOpenFilename)
     Image2.Picture = Image1.Picture
 ErrHandler:
 ActiveSheet.Range("C8").Select
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

I have several other sheets in the workbook and I want to change all of the images to the same as on the first sheet. These images will be transparent gif files. Further, all pages are protected.

I have tried to do it this way, with no success:

```
 Dim WS as Worksheet
 Set WS = Sheets(2)
 With WS
    .OLEObjects("Image1").Object.Picture = Image1.Picture
 End With
```

Can anyone advise me how to make this happen?

***Thank you very much in advance!***

Comment: What's the error you encounter and which line throws it? Where's located the sub with the offending line?

Comment: I do have a suitable code in my library for inserting an image into the specific cell of worksheet from image control on the userForm. If it helps and can be adapted to your situation, I can post it as an Answer as it would not be covered in the comments.

Comment: It is just not populating the other image controls on the other pages. Simply, I just want to select the desired image on the first sheet (which works fine) and the have it update all the other image sheets on the various pages with same picture.

Comment: If you can imagine, the first sheet is a dashboard of sorts and the image selected is a transparent image of a signature which is being applied several times throughout the workbook.  The only error I am getting is when I double click the first image control on the first sheet, the file picker opens but if I click 'CANCEL' it was throwing an error.